# Is there a Loop function in Tableau Prep? (Problem written below)

Tags: loops, data-cleaning, tableau-api

I'm working on multiple datasets and currently, I'm in the cleaning process. I have a column that contains phone-model names. What I am required to do, is to change the phone model name to the phone brand. example: instead of Touch Pro2 (phone model) as a name, this should be changed to HTC (phone brand). I have another phone_dataset that contains all phone models corresponding to their phone brands. What I want to do is to cross the two datasets (the main dataset and the phone_dataset) and create a loop that dictates, if the model column value of the main dataset, corresponds to the model column value of phone_dataset, then change it with the brand column value of phone_dataset.

The way I thought about the solution is the following:

If we consider T1: main dataset model-table & T2: phone dataset model-table & T3: phone dataset brand-table then

this should be written as:

```
i = 1

For i in main table

j = 1

While T1[j] =! T2 [j] 

If T1[j] = T2[j] Then 

     T1[j] == T3[j]
```

I don't know if there is a loop function that I can use in the calculated field, or how to do the whole process exactly? if not, what should I do?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: perhaps try a join followed  by a clean step to introduce a calculated field

Comment: Don't try and reinvent the wheel. Database systems handle this sort of problem easily without you having to code loops.